# Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric. Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente código y cuando quiero guardar en tabla (SQL Server) me da el siguiente error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric.'` Todo es por la variable *indice*.
Intenté lo siguiente: `TxtIndice.text = indice` y en la consulta sql en lugar de la variable poner `val(txtIndice.text)`, con lo que no da error, pero en la tabla me graba un 0 porque el textbox me recorta los decimales.

```vb
Dim porcentaje As Integer
Dim indice As Decimal
porcentaje = TxtPorcentaje.Text

indice = (100 - porcentaje) / 100


Dim NuevaBeca As String = "UPDATE beca SET tipo_beca = '" & TxtTipoBeca.Text & "', descuento_beca = '" & indice & "' WHERE codigo_beca = '" & codigo & "'"
Dim comando As New SqlCommand(NuevaBeca, conexion)
comando.ExecuteNonQuery()

If comando.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("" & TxtTipoBeca.Text & " se incorporó correctamente")

Else
    MsgBox("¡Error! Datos no guardados. Reinicie el programa e intente nuevamente")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo cambiando, en la configuración regional de mi PC, el formato de número con coma como separador de miles y el punto para los decimales.
Pero como soy algo nuevo en programación supongo que hay una forma de hacerlo por código en el programa (lo que me resultaría más adecuado). No me gustaría hacer una aplicación que solo le funcione al usuario  con determinada configuración de su sistema. Con ánimo de aprender espero que alguien me ayude, ya sea diciéndome que lo que hice es la solución adecuada o que hay forma de hacerlo por código. Muchas gracias.